# Bootstrap Carousels not loading/displaying properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

Everything on the site works fine. I'm trying to implement a bootstrap carousel however they are not sliding whatsoever, I have tried a few examples on bootsnip and even the one on the official website isn't working? Anyone have any idea why? I thought it might be because of the javascript link but it looks fine?

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>The Beckwood - Scunthorpe</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="header-main">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" >
                     <img src="assets/img/logo.png">

                </a>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a id="activenav" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                         <li><a href="menu.html">MENU</a></li>
                          <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
                           <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="book.html">BOOK A TABLE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="hero">
            <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to The Beckwood.</h1>
            <p>The Beckwood is a family run pub located in scunthorpe offering quality homemade food, carverys, events and live sports.</p>
            <div class="btn btn-primary"><a href="menu.html">View Menu</a></div>
            <div class="btn btn-primary"><a href="menu.html">Book a table</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="intro">
        <h1> Quality Food, Drinks and Atmosphere! </h1>
        <p>Welcome to the Beckwood! Here at the beckwood we specialise in authentic home made dishes hand cooked by our chefs.<br> Not only do we offer beautiful food we also provide entertainment, live sports and great quality beer.<br> Not only do we offer beautiful food we also provide entertainment.</p>
    </div>
</div>


<!--about-->
  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center marb-35">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="about-info">
              <h2 class="heading">A small heading goes here</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero impedit inventore culpa vero accusamus in nostrum dignissimos modi, molestiae. Autem iusto esse necessitatibus ex corporis earum quaerat voluptates quibusdam dicta!</p>
               <h2 class="heading">A small heading goes here</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero impedit inventore culpa vero accusamus in nostrum dignissimos modi, molestiae. Autem iusto esse necessitatibus ex corporis earum quaerat voluptates quibusdam dicta!consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero impedit inventore culpa vero accusamus in nostrum dignissimos modi, </p>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <img id="beckwoodabout" src="assets/img/image1.jpeg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
  </section>
  <!--/about-->

  <div class="homebar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 margin-b-30">
                        <h2>Our Carvery</h2>
                        <img id="carvpic"  src="assets/img/carvery.jpg"><br><br>
                        <div class="overflow-hidden">

                            <p>lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.
                            lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.
                            lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.
                            lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.</p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><a href="book.html">Book Now</a></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 margin-b-30">
                        <h2>Events</h2>
                        <img id="carvpic"  src="assets/img/events.jpg"><br><br>
                        <p>lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.
                            lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.
                            lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.
                            lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.</p>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><a href="book.html">Book Now</a></button>
                        <div class="overflow-hidden">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 margin-b-30">
                        <h2>Function Room</h2>
                         <img id="carvpic"  src="assets/img/functionroom.jpg"><br><br>
                        <div class="overflow-hidden">
 <p>lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.
                            lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.
                            lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.
                            lorem ipsum and beckwood this is a test.</p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><a href="book.html">Book Now</a></button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<br><br>



<iframe id="maps"
  width="100%"
  height="300px"
  padding="0px"
  margin="0px"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyB0d_sYwCWD5owhYY4UYb-i7VlOOnx2_o4

    &q=The Beckwood,Scunthorpe" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>

<footer id="myFooter">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <img id="footerlogo" src="assets/img/logo.png">



                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h5>Opening Times</h5>

                             <p class="opening hours"></p>
                    <p>Tue-Thu ~ 12:00 - 23:00</p>
                    <p>Friday ~ 12:00 - 00:00</p>
                    <p>Saturday ~ 12:00 - 00:00</p>
                    <p>Sunday ~ 12:00 - 22:30</p>


                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <h5>Navigation</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="social-networks">
                        <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>

<img class="center" src="assets/img/hygeine.png">


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            <p>© 2018 The Beckwood.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="validator.js"></script>
<script src="contact.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser's developer tools console for errors?

Comment: Also, try more than one browser. IE often problematic. Have you tried both Chrome and FF?

Comment: Yes im using chrome atm, the only error i get is Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: So which file isn't found??

Comment: hmm, it does't say

Comment: They all seem to display properly its just the actual carousel feature isn't working ie the button wont slide and there is no animation? Could this be a javascript problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to import the Bootstrap and JS in the `<head>` tags.

Hope it helps

Comment: Nope. Read the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: @j08691 I noticed Harry is importing Bootstrap3 at the top and 4 at the bottom of the file. Would that cause any conflicting errors?

Comment: It's possible .

Comment: hey guys, that was the problem, I changed my JavaScript version to same as bootstrap and it worked! Thanks for the help